How to build a model where each data point has different levels of information?
Let’s say I want to predict the weight of a person given information about them; height & sex.
Now, let’s say that that I have additional information about roughly 50% of the individuals included in the dataset - I know their age, occupation & nationality.
How do I best build a model that encompasses all of this?
If I just build a model with the 2 features I know about every person (height, sex), then I’ll be losing critical information regarding people I know more about.
At the same time, I don’t want to build 2 separate models, because the model with the richer features will be losing data/knowledge from the data I have to get rid of.
How do you go about a problem like this?

You could look at all five features and then treat age, occupation and nationality as features with missing values. You can find many methods to handle missing values online.
